# .Net 8 Blazor share component state across web clients

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I'm enjoying .Net8 Blazor, and there's lots of new stuff to learn.

I need a second set of eyes on this. My outcome is sharing the state of a dynamically loaded component across all clients. If there are multiple instances of the plugin, they each maintain their state across all clients.

*Note: This is a server-side project.

My thought was to cache a list of the RenderFragment and display it to each client page load. However, after stepping through a page load containing the cached RenderFragment, the component class is instantiated for each page load, and therefore the variables within the class are initialized. My conclusion is the RenderFragment does not contain an instantiated class of the component.

My question is, does anyone have suggestions on maintaining the state of the components to be shared across client page loads?

I'm dynamically loading a component from a DLL, instantiating it, generating a render fragment, and caching it...

```
    public void btnAddPlugin() {

      string dllFile = @"PluginExampleComponent.dll";

      var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFile);

      var types = assembly.GetTypes();

      foreach (var type in types)
        if (typeof(IPluginTemplate).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {

          var skill = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IPluginTemplate;

          if (skill != null) {

            RenderFragment renderFragment = (builder) => {
              builder.OpenComponent(0, skill.GetType());
              builder.CloseComponent();
            };

            var pluginManagerItem = new PluginManagerItem() {
              RenderFragment = renderFragment,
              RobotSkill = skill
            };

            _pluginManager.AddSkill(pluginManagerItem);
          }
        }
    }
```

On a view plugins page, I am looping through the cache and displaying the render fragment to display the plugins on client page loads.

```
@page "/ViewPlugins"
@using System.Reflection

<PageTitle>Plugins</PageTitle>

<div class="container">

  @foreach (var plugin in _pluginManager.Plugins) {

    @plugin.RenderFragment
  }

</div>
```

Here is the plugin code...

```
<p>
  Counter: @_counter
</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="btnIncrement">Click me</button>
```

And the code behind is...

```
namespace PluginComponent {

  public partial class TestPlugin {

    // This is the variable I expect to maintain across page loads
    // I assumed the class was instantiated with the Render Fragment builder
    // and therefor would maintain across rendered fragement references
    public int _counter = 0;
  }
}
```

I expect that each instance of the "plugin" displays the _counter, assuming the class was instantiated only once during the render fragment builder. I feel what I'm trying to do has been thought of by the.Net8 developers.

###Additional Information
An interesting bug report defines a similar behavior but only across one "session", initially described as "by design", then recalled. I want a similar experience but across all client page loads. Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52102

Comment: A component is a rule for the expression of information.  You should only ever persist the information, not the actual component itself.  In Blazor, there are 4 main ways to persist data: 1) Cascading it from the parent page or even the layout page; 2) using direct injection (Singleton = shared across all users; Scoped = shared across all pages of current client session; Transient= not persistent); 3) saving info to a DB and reloading it usually in OnInitialized; 4) (if it's very simple data like an ID) passing it as a parameter in a navigation query.

Comment: If I inject a singleton, can it access the component’s Public objects?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "public object"?  An injected class can be used freely in whatever component or class you inject it.

Comment: A component has objects within the class that hold the data to be rendered. In my example above, it's _counter. A service is injected, so the service has no reference to the parent - or does it? I'm wondering if from the service I can get a reference to the component that injected it. That way, I can access the component objects from the injected service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh geez, there's a lot to take in. The answer was in front of me the whole time. I kept seeing "cascade parameter" stuff and didn't think the name description applied to me. I was wrong :)

```
<CascadingValue Value=@this>
  @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
```

I may use it differently than intended for my unique use case. But it works!